# Roadmap to reach Arithmetic Geometry for a Physics Major

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am a physics major but I self-study mathematics. my interests are number theory and geometry. it seems that due to the works of *Grothendieck*, algebraic geometry have to be used to study deepest problems of number theory which culminates in *Arithmetic Geometry* or *Arithmetic Algebraic Geometry* (**Please correct me if this isn't true!**). I would really appreciate it if someone can provide me an elementary roadmap to reach Arithmetic Geometry.

I have read Knapp's "[Basic Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817632506)" and "[Basic Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817632484)" and my motivation for choosing these books was that in the second volume of Knapp's Algebra, one will become familiar with the language of number theory and also methods of algebraic geometry which is used to study number theory. any comment about Knapp's books also would be really helpful.

Any comment would greatly be appreciated!

Thank YOU!

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21552/roadmap-for-studying-arithmetic-geometry, http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller/bin/emerton-roadmap.pdf, and http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/research.html#students

Comment: Dear @KCd!
Thank you for these links! they are really helpful.

Comment: Lorenzini has a book called *An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry* that may suit your needs.

Comment: I second @KCd's suggestions whole-heartedly (he really knows the subject). And Emerton, linked to in his comment, is a great arithmetic geometer, unfortunately no longer very active on this site: a great loss.

Comment: @Hoot, I have already read the book. I am now trying to understand the schemes. I hope in a couple of years from now, I can understand what Peter Scholze is doing. It is very ambitious, but I hope I can do it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Milne's website:

http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/index.html

Read everything. Start by simultaneously reading "Elliptic Curves" with "Algebraic Number Theory" and "Algebraic Geometry." Then read whatever else of his, as the spirit moves you.

Comment: "Read everything" is a hilarious piece of advice.  Have  you read and understood *Class Field Theory, Lectures on  Etale Cohomology, Reductive groups, Abelian Varieties*, dear hunter (and @guest) ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I do not understand the aggressive remark.  Isn't 'read everything' obvious hyperbole, implying that everything in that website is important for Arithmetic Geometry?  And isn't it true?  In fact, doesn't the last paragraph of hunter's answer clearly reveal that he does not really mean the OP to literally read everything?

Comment: @guest: yes, everything in that website is important for Arithmetic Geometry and yes, the answer is obvious hyperbole. But then what is the OP concretely supposed to do with this hyperbolic advice ? I suggest: "Read everything that Weil, Grothendieck, Deligne and  Faltings  have published" :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg hunter recommended an excellent website of free online books that provide entry into the subject.  He concretely suggested the OP *starts with the books EC, ANT, and AG* which is far more specific than the *everything* you keep focusing on.  If you think this recommendation is bad or incomplete or can be improved, write a comment with suggestions to hunter on how to improve it.  Expressing your amusement at the user's 'hilarious' attempt at an answer and ending with a condescending 'dear hunter' is the opposite of constructive and does not contribute anything.

Comment: Dear @guest, about 80%  of my comments start with or contain dear(name of user) or dear@(name of user).